# Selenium web driver and csv file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, opencsv

I have data in csv file and also integrate with Selenium.
The test scenario is Search the name of product and verify that the Product name, category, Brand and sub-category according to the document or not? Please Help if it is possible.
Here is my code

```
public class ProductVerification {
    public String baseurl="https://souqofqatar.com/admin";
    String driverPath="C:\\Users\\Novatore\\Desktop\\Selenium-Drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
    String CSV_file="CSVdatafile\\Cat-Home Appliances and SubCat-Home Comfort (1).csv";
    static WebDriver driver;
    String line="";
    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath);
        driver =new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"admin_user_email\"]")).sendKeys("admin@example.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"admin_user_password\"]")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/fieldset[2]/ol/li/input")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/a")).click();
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(450,0)", "");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    @Test
    public void search() throws InterruptedException, IOException, CsvException {
        File file = new File(CSV_file);
        if(file.exists()){
         System.out.println("File Exists");
        }
        try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((line=br.readLine()) !=null){
            while((line=br.readLine()) !=null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            String row= (values[1]);
            
            for (int i=0; row!=null;i++) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"q_name\"]")).sendKeys(""+row);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[9]/input[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                String name=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='col col-name']")).getText();
                System.out.println(name);
                if(name!=row) {
                    System.out.println(name+" Not find");
                }
            }   
        }
        }}catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
            }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
            }
        
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void CloseBrowser() {
    driver.close(); 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please share more clear details like the example csv file and 1 sample test case which successfully verifies your requirement

Comment: Want to test the product data. It consists of Product name, category, sub-category and Brand. All data provided in CSV.

Comment: Want to test the product data. It consists of Product name, category, sub-category and Brand. All data provided in CSV. How can i perform action like get Product name and verify its Category, sub-category and Brand.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Not Getting any error. i am failed to make logic of that task.
I have uploaded csv successfully and can view the data but confuses in logic. How compare the searched data that it is equal to our required data and how many time loop run and control shift in next item?